# Index Formula with condition - Excel 2010

Tags: excel

I have a table in Sheet: TeamDetails with employee details as following
**Name Domain ect.. etc.. and Status**

Status column contains Active OR In Active

In my Dashboard sheet, all the employees of a certain domain are displayed when you select the domain name from a Data Validation list(Cell: F32).

Current **Array** Formula:

`{=IFERROR(INDEX(TeamDetails[Name],`
   `SMALL(IF(TeamDetails[Domain]=Dashboard!$F$32,ROW(TeamDetails[Domain])-ROW(TeamDetails!$D$4)+1),`
    `ROWS(TeamDetails!$D$4:TeamDetails!$D4))`
    `),"No Team")}`

**My Question:** The above formula displays all employees including those whose status are "In Active" too which is something I want to avoid. 
Please Help! (No VBA please)
Excel Knowledge: Beginner

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to throw in a second condition and multiply it into the first one.  I assume the second condition will be of the form `TeamDetails[Status] = "Active"`.  Combining that with the first condition gives:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TeamDetails[Name], SMALL(IF((TeamDetails[Domain]=Dashboard!$F$32)*(TeamDetails[Status]="Active"),ROW(TeamDetails[Domain])-ROW(TeamDetails!$D$4)+1),  ROWS(TeamDetails!$D$4:TeamDetails!$D4))  ),"No Team")
```

Comment: This worked like magic. Now when I look into your solution, I question my lack of logical thinking! Thank you Byron.